# SQL Server deserialize XML into table

Tags: sql-server, xml, serialization

I have generate many xml with the SQL Server command : FOR XML RAW
In that way i have filled a table with the following schema

| ACTION as CHAR(1) | TABLE_NAME as NVARCHAR(25) | PAYLOAD as NVARCHAR(MAX) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| I | tbl_1 | xmlrow_1 |
| I | tbl_1 | xmlrow_2 |
| U | tbl_1 | xmlrow_3 |
| D | tbl_1 | xmlrow_4 |
| D | tbl_2 | xmlrow_5 |

ACTION is a char ( I = insert, U = update, D = delete)
TABLE_NAME is the table on which i have to act (for insert the data, update it or delete it)
PAYLOAD is a XML serialized by SQL Server using the command FOR XML RAW on original table

PAYLOAD Example :

```
<row COL1="val_col_1" COL2="val_col_2" .. COLN="val_col_n"/>
```

I am looking for a way (i am writing a stored procedure so i am looking for TSQL) to deserialize it on the "configured" TABLE_NAME possibly for the UPSERT.
If this is not faseable (as i suspect) i will build the SQL script for insert,update or delete dynamically but i still need to deserialize the XML in the PAYLOAD and don't know how to do

I mean, if there is not a better way, how i can do some like that ?

```
UPDATE [dbo].[tbl_1]
SET [COL1] = CURRENT_ROW.COL1
   ,[COL2] = CURRENT_ROW.COL2
   ,[COL3] = CURRENT_ROW.COL3
FROM ( xmlrow_3 --DESERIALIZE ) AS CURRENT_ROW
```

--EIDTED : added working example in fiddler
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ac5925a0a2f93791cc7e7c34179137ae

Comment: added example of what i looking for (even if it's not clear the faseability)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky : my apologies, i haven't understand that this policy apply to every question. I have thought was 'only' for question related to bug. I'll integrate my question ASAP